# javascript forEach multiple function array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

I have source code, how to output forEach arrise.tester2 only or JSON stringify perhaps?
This is the code :

```
var arrise = [{"tester1":"testo","tester2":["testi1","testi2"]},{"tester1":"testc","tester2":["test1","test2"]},{"tester1":"testd","tester3":["tes1","tes3"]}];
```

Comment: what means output? a new array with just this property?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` and `array#filter`. Visit each object in the array and check for `tester2` key.

```js
var arrise = [{"tester1":"testo","tester2":["testi1","testi2"]},{"tester1":"testc","tester2":["test1","test2"]},{"tester1":"testd","tester3":["tes1","tes3"]}];

var result = arrise
              .map(o => o.tester2)
              .filter(x => x);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: how add break, and how to filter only tester[0]. example output:  testi1,test1,tes1

Comment: Change `.map(o => o.tester2)` to `.map(o => o.tester2 && o.tester2[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You could filter first by checking the property and then mapp the values.

```js
var arrise = [{ tester1: "testo", tester2: ["testi1", "testi2"] },{ tester1: "testc", tester2: ["test1", "test2"] }, { tester1: "testd", tester3:["tes1", "tes3"] }],
    tester2 = arrise
        .filter(o => o.tester2)
        .map(o => o.tester2);

console.log(tester2);
```